# Linq returning null error after entity framework update

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I had line of code that worked perfectly...

```
b = db.viewMaterijalis.Where(p => p.sifra_pozicije == pozicija).Sum(p => p.ukupno);
```

Recently i updated visual studio 2013 packages from nuget manager, including entity framework (from 6.0 to 6.1) and mvc (from 5.0 to 5.1).

Now my code throws an error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

update:
I managed to locate error in `.sum()`, but no idea how to fix it. I tried to check if sum returns null value with `b.Sum(p=>p.ukupno).HasValue`, but again it raises an exception.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

EF 6.1 is still in beta, so you may have just found a bug!